# Pandas: How to get the row-column value from a data frame of ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame `df1` of ranges `(start, end)`:

```
 ID  |   Y_b1            c1_t              rd1_hd          bd_n9              
---- |----------------------------------------------------------------
 a   |   1, 5                              654, 678        11, 15
 b   |                   88761, 88776  
 6c  |   1211, 1215                        38, 47    
 2d  |   89, 95          3, 19                             1567, 1578
```

And another data frame `df2`:

```
Owner           product                 
Abi             1                               
John            678          
Lan             13
Smith           90               
Tim             670 
Don             4
```

I'd like to have a third column in `df2` that gives the `row-column` name of the cell in `df1` that contains the range(s) within which the values in `df2['product']` can be found.

I'd like the final `df3` to look like this:

```
Owner           product          Source       
Abi             1                a-Y_b1               
John            678              a-rd1_hd
Lan             13               2d-c1_t, a-bd_n9
Smith           90               2d-Y_b1
Tim             670              a-rd1_hd 
Don             4                a-Y_b1, 2d-c1_t
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow each step ; 1) melt -> 2) cross -> 3) keep in range-> 4) reshape & concat -> 5) final

```
# 00) module

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#0) datasets

dict={'ID':['a', 'b', '6c', '2d'],
     'Y_b1':['1, 5', None, '1211, 1215', '89, 95'],
     'c1_t':[None, '88761, 88776', None, '3, 19'],
     'rd1_hd':['654, 678', None, '38, 47', None],
     'bd_n9':['11, 15', None, None, '1567, 1578']
     }

dict2={'Owner':['Abi', 'John', 'Lan', 'Smith', 'Tim', 'Don'],
       'product':[1, 678, 13, 90, 670, 4]
       }

     
df1=pd.DataFrame(dict)
df2=pd.DataFrame(dict2)
print(df1)
print(df2)

# 1) melt

var=list(df1.drop(columns='ID').columns)
print(var)
melt=pd.melt(df1,id_vars='ID',value_vars=var)
melt['source']=melt['ID']+'-'+melt['variable']
melt=melt.drop(columns=['ID','variable'])


melt=pd.concat([melt,melt.value.str.split(pat=',',expand=True)],axis=1)
melt[0]=melt[0].astype('float')
melt[1]=melt[1].astype('float')
print(melt)

#           value     source        0        1
#0           1, 5     a-Y_b1      1.0      5.0
#1           None     b-Y_b1      NaN      NaN
#2     1211, 1215    6c-Y_b1   1211.0   1215.0
#3         89, 95    2d-Y_b1     89.0     95.0
#4           None     a-c1_t      NaN      NaN
#5   88761, 88776     b-c1_t  88761.0  88776.0
#6           None    6c-c1_t      NaN      NaN
#7          3, 19    2d-c1_t      3.0     19.0
#8       654, 678   a-rd1_hd    654.0    678.0
#9           None   b-rd1_hd      NaN      NaN
#10        38, 47  6c-rd1_hd     38.0     47.0
#11          None  2d-rd1_hd      NaN      NaN
#12        11, 15    a-bd_n9     11.0     15.0
#13          None    b-bd_n9      NaN      NaN
#14          None   6c-bd_n9      NaN      NaN
#15    1567, 1578   2d-bd_n9   1567.0   1578.0


# 2) cross

cross=df2.merge(melt,how='cross').dropna()
print(cross)

# 3) keep in range

keep=cross.loc[(cross['product']>=cross[0]) & (cross['product']<=cross[1]),:]
keep=keep.loc[:,['Owner','product','source']]
print(keep)

#    Owner  product    source
#0     Abi        1    a-Y_b1
#24   John      678  a-rd1_hd
#39    Lan       13   2d-c1_t
#44    Lan       13   a-bd_n9
#51  Smith       90   2d-Y_b1
#72    Tim      670  a-rd1_hd
#80    Don        4    a-Y_b1
#87    Don        4   2d-c1_t


# 4) reshape & concat

keep['a']=keep.Owner+'_'+keep['product'].astype('str')
for i in keep.a.unique():
    keep.loc[keep.a==i,'no']=list(range(1,keep.loc[keep.a==i].shape[0]+1))
keep=keep.drop(columns='a')
keep.loc[:,'no']=keep.no.astype('int')
print(keep)

#    Owner  product    source  no
#0     Abi        1    a-Y_b1   1
#24   John      678  a-rd1_hd   1
#39    Lan       13   2d-c1_t   1
#44    Lan       13   a-bd_n9   2
#51  Smith       90   2d-Y_b1   1
#72    Tim      670  a-rd1_hd   1
#80    Don        4    a-Y_b1   1
#87    Don        4   2d-c1_t   2



reshape=keep.pivot(index=['Owner','product'],columns='no',values='source') # NOT pivot_table
print(reshape)

for i in reshape.loc[:,1:2].columns:

    if list(reshape.loc[:,1:2].columns)[0]==locals()['i']:
        reshape['concat']=reshape[locals()['i']]

    else:
        reshape['concat']=reshape['concat'].str.cat(reshape[locals()['i']],sep=', ',na_rep='delete')

reshape.concat=reshape.concat.str.replace(', delete','')
print(reshape)

#no                    1        2            concat
#Owner product                                     
#Abi   1          a-Y_b1      NaN            a-Y_b1
#Don   4          a-Y_b1  2d-c1_t   a-Y_b1, 2d-c1_t
#John  678      a-rd1_hd      NaN          a-rd1_hd
#Lan   13        2d-c1_t  a-bd_n9  2d-c1_t, a-bd_n9
#Smith 90        2d-Y_b1      NaN           2d-Y_b1
#Tim   670      a-rd1_hd      NaN          a-rd1_hd


# 5) final

final=reshape.reset_index().loc[:,['Owner','product','concat']]
final=final.rename(columns={'concat':'source'})
print(final)

#no  Owner  product            source
#0     Abi        1            a-Y_b1
#1     Don        4   a-Y_b1, 2d-c1_t
#2    John      678          a-rd1_hd
#3     Lan       13  2d-c1_t, a-bd_n9
#4   Smith       90           2d-Y_b1
#5     Tim      670          a-rd1_hd
```

this code below is stata code. data work through Stata is easier.

```
  clear
  set more off
  edit
  
  cd d:/ // working directory
  
  ***************************************************
  * make datasets
  ***************************************************
  
  * data1
  
  input str12(ID    Y_b1    c1_t    rd1_hd  bd_n9)
  "a"   "1, 5"  ""  "654, 678"  "11, 15"
  "b"   ""  "88761, 88776"  ""  ""
  "6c"  "1211, 1215"    ""  "38, 47"    ""
  "2d"  "89, 95"    "3, 19" ""  "1567, 1578"
  end
  
  save data1.dta,replace
  
  * data2
  
  clear
  input str5(Owner)  product                 
  Abi    1                               
  John   678          
  Lan    13
  Smith  90               
  Tim    670 
  Don    4  
  end
  save data2.dta,replace
  
  ***************************************************
  
  ***************************************************
  * data work
  ***************************************************
  
  * 1) reshape long(python: melt)
  
  use data1,clear
  ren * v_*
  ren v_ID ID
  
  reshape long v_ ,i(ID) j(var) string
  drop if missing(v_)
  split v_ ,p(,) gen(num)
  destring num*,replace
  drop v_
  list,sep(0)
 /* 
   +-----------------------------+
   | ID      var    num1    num2 |
   |-----------------------------|
1. | 2d     Y_b1      89      95 |
2. | 2d    bd_n9    1567    1578 |
3. | 2d     c1_t       3      19 |
4. | 6c     Y_b1    1211    1215 |
5. | 6c   rd1_hd      38      47 |
6. |  a     Y_b1       1       5 |
7. |  a    bd_n9      11      15 |
8. |  a   rd1_hd     654     678 |
9. |  b     c1_t   88761   88776 |
   +-----------------------------+
*/

  * 2) cross
  
  cross using  data2.dta
  
  
  * 3) keep in range
  
  keep if product>=num1 & product<=num2
  gen index=ID+"-"+var
  keep Owner product index
  
  
  list,sep(0)
 /* 
   +----------------------------+
   | Owner   product      index |
   |----------------------------|
1. |   Abi         1     a-Y_b1 |
2. | Smith        90    2d-Y_b1 |
3. |   Lan        13    2d-c1_t |
4. |   Don         4    2d-c1_t |
5. |   Don         4     a-Y_b1 |
6. |   Lan        13    a-bd_n9 |
7. |  John       678   a-rd1_hd |
8. |   Tim       670   a-rd1_hd |
   +----------------------------+
*/

  * 4) reshape & concat
  
  bysort Owner product: gen no=_n
  list,sep(0)
 /* 
   +---------------------------------+
   | Owner   product      index   no |
   |---------------------------------|
1. |   Abi         1     a-Y_b1    1 |
2. |   Don         4     a-Y_b1    1 |
3. |   Don         4    2d-c1_t    2 |
4. |  John       678   a-rd1_hd    1 |
5. |   Lan        13    a-bd_n9    1 |
6. |   Lan        13    2d-c1_t    2 |
7. | Smith        90    2d-Y_b1    1 |
8. |   Tim       670   a-rd1_hd    1 |
   +---------------------------------+
*/
  
  reshape wide index ,i(Owner product) j(no)
  reshape long 
  replace index="delete" if missing(index)
  reshape wide
  
  egen Source=concat(index*) ,p(", ")
  replace Source=subinstr(Source,", delete","",.)
  list,sep(0)
/*  
   +---------------------------------------------------------+
   | Owner   product     index1    index2             Source |
   |---------------------------------------------------------|
1. |   Abi         1     a-Y_b1    delete             a-Y_b1 |
2. |   Don         4     a-Y_b1   2d-c1_t    a-Y_b1, 2d-c1_t |
3. |  John       678   a-rd1_hd    delete           a-rd1_hd |
4. |   Lan        13    a-bd_n9   2d-c1_t   a-bd_n9, 2d-c1_t |
5. | Smith        90    2d-Y_b1    delete            2d-Y_b1 |
6. |   Tim       670   a-rd1_hd    delete           a-rd1_hd |
   +---------------------------------------------------------+
*/
  
  *5) final
  
  drop index* // index* indicates columns name of which starts with index
  order Owner product Source
  list,sep(0)
  /*
   +------------------------------------+
   | Owner   product             Source |
   |------------------------------------|
1. |   Abi         1             a-Y_b1 |
2. |   Don         4    a-Y_b1, 2d-c1_t |
3. |  John       678           a-rd1_hd |
4. |   Lan        13   a-bd_n9, 2d-c1_t |
5. | Smith        90            2d-Y_b1 |
6. |   Tim       670           a-rd1_hd |
   +------------------------------------+
*/
  
  ***************************************************
```

Comment: The line ```print(cross)``` gives an error message: ```raise MergeError(
pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False```

Comment: @cave  did the line, `cross = df2.merge(melt, how='cross').dropna()` give an error message? my intention of `print(cross)` was just to check or see the result. could you check pandas version you use?

Comment: Yes, it gave an error. How can I check the pandas version?

Comment: @cave type `pd.__version__` , and type(pd.DataFrame.merge) in order to check how ur pandas merge works when how='cross'. my pandas version is 1.3.0

Comment: I use ```version 1.1.3```. And ```pd.DataFrame.merge``` gives ```<function DataFrame.merge at 0x7fd4e5e00e50>```

Comment: @cave sorry! it was type `help(pd.DataFrame.merge)`

Comment: This line doesn't work ```melt[0]=melt[0].astype('float')```. It says: ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''```

Comment: @cave  '' dosn't mean missing value. you seem to applicate my code into ur actuall data.  because '' IS NOT missing value, you should change '' into missing value(None or np.nan) in 0 column and 1 column 

`melt.loc[melt[0]=='',:]=np.nan`
`melt.loc[melt[1]=='',:]=np.nan`

then 'melt[0]=melt[0].astype('float')' will work

Comment: Yes, I'm using the code on my actual data. I have done ```import numpy as np```, and put the 2 lines of code ```melt.loc[melt[0]=='',:]=np.nan``` and ```melt.loc[melt[1]=='',:]=np.nan``` In the next 2 lines, I have: ```melt[0]=melt[0].astype('float')```  and ```melt[1]=melt[1].astype('float')``` but I still got an error: ```return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True).``` ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235173/discussion-between-cave-and-sanzo213).

Comment: @sanzo213 FYI using `dict` as a variable name steps on the Python built-in `dict` class.  This has caused me unneeded pain in the past.